# Simple prime number program - Weird issue with threads C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace FirePrime
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool[] ThreadsFinished;
        static bool[] nums;

        static bool AllThreadsFinished()
        {
            bool allThreadsFinished = false;
            foreach (var threadFinished in ThreadsFinished)
            {
                allThreadsFinished &= threadFinished;
            }
            return allThreadsFinished;
        }

        static bool isPrime(int n)
        {
            if (n < 2) { return false; }
            if (n == 2) { return true; }
            if (n % 2 == 0) { return false; }
            int d = 3;
            while (d * d <= n)
            {
                if (n % d == 0) { return false; }
                d += 2;
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void MarkPrimes(int startNumber,int stopNumber,int ThreadNr)
        {
            for (int j = startNumber; j < stopNumber; j++)
                nums[j] = isPrime(j);
            lock (typeof(Program))
            {
                ThreadsFinished[ThreadNr] = true;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int nrNums = 100;
            int nrThreads = 10;
            //var threadStartNums = new List<int>();

            ThreadsFinished = new bool[nrThreads];

            nums = new bool[nrNums];
            //var nums = new List<bool>();
            nums[0] = false;
            nums[1] = false;
            for(int i=2;i<nrNums;i++)
                nums[i] = true;

            int interval = (int)(nrNums / nrThreads);
            //threadStartNums.Add(2);
            //int aux = firstStartNum;
            //int i = 2;
            //while (aux < interval)
            //{
            //    aux = interval*i;
            //    i=i+1;
            //    threadStartNums.Add(aux);
            //}

            int startNum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nrThreads; i++)
            {

                var _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => MarkPrimes(startNum, Math.Min(startNum + interval, nrNums), i));
                startNum = startNum + interval;
                //set the thread to run in the background
                _thread.IsBackground = true;
                //start our thread
                _thread.Start();
            }

            while (!AllThreadsFinished())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nrNums; i++)
                if(nums[i])
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This should be a pretty simple program that is supposed to find and output the first `nrNums` prime numbers using `nrThreads` threads working in parallel.

So, I just split `nrNums` into `nrThreads` equal chunks (well, the last one won't be equal; if `nrThreads` doesn't divide by `nrNums`, it will also contain the remainder, of course).

I start `nrThreads` threads.

They all test each number in their respective chunk and see if it is prime or not; they mark everything out in a bool array that keeps a tab on all the primes.

The threads all turn a specific element in another boolean array `ThreadsFinished` to true when they finish.

Now the weird part begins:

The threads never all end. If I debug, I find that `ThreadNr` is not what I assign to it in the loop but another value.
I guess this is normal since the threads execute afterwards and the counter (the variable i) is already increased by then but I cannot understand how to make the code be right.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance.

P.S.:  I know the algorithm is not very efficient; I am aiming at a solution using the sieve of Eratosthenes also with x given threads.  But for now I can't even get this one to work and I haven't found any examples of any implementations of that algorithm anywhere in a language that I can understand.

Comment: Just a quick drive-by comment: Instead of looping while `AllThreadsFinished()` is false, you should [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) on each thread one at a time -- each call will block until the respective thread has terminated.  This is a much more CPU-efficient way to wait for threads to finish.

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes can't be parallelized: You've got one prime number, you mark all it's multiples as not being primes. You move to the next non-marked number, print it out because it's an prime and repeat. What would two separate threads do?

Comment: @Cosmin Prund well it says here http://cs-alb-pc3.massey.ac.nz/notes/59735/seminars/01077635.pdf that it can be and gives an algorithm. I haven't researched the problem much and in school I only implemented it in a non parallel fashion. I only mentioned it because I knew it to be one of the fastest methods of finding primes.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund you can parallelise it by having enough communication between the threads so each thread marking off multiples in the sieve is always operating on numbers higher than the thread reading the primes. With light enough concurrency, you can have one task per prime and wake them periodically for each block of numbers for them to mark off. Alteratively, since all primes contributing to a block starting at *k* are less than *sqrt(k)*, process blocks in separate threads.

Comment: @Para: Are you aware of the new [Parallel class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx) in C# 4.0, which makes much of your manual book-keeping unnecessary?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft I am aware of it but the requirement was for a specified number of threads to run concurrently. I don't know how to run a specified number of threads with the Parallel class. It starts as many threads as it wants. This looks like a good implementation with parallel to find primes with the sieve of atkins http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2010/01/14/prime-factorization-in-parallel but overall not exactly within the requirements

Comment: @Cosmin Prund my implementation of the sieve in parallel http://paratechnical.blogspot.com/2011/01/c-implementation-of-parallel-sieve-of.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value the thread receives is the one `startNum` holds when the thread runs. To solve it copy the value into a local variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrThreads; i++)
{
 var localStartNum = startNum; // save value in local variable
                                  // and use in the thread start
    var localIndex = i;

 var _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => 
                      MarkPrimes(localStartNum,
                                 Math.Min(localStartNum + interval, nrNums),
                                 localIndex));
 startNum = startNum + interval;
 _thread.IsBackground = true;
 _thread.Start();
}
```

Another bug in the code is waiting for all threads:

```
static bool AllThreadsFinished()
{
    bool allThreadsFinished = true; // Initialize to true instead of false
                                    // Otherwise, all ANDs will result false
    foreach (var threadFinished in ThreadsFinished)
    {
        allThreadsFinished = threadFinished;
    }

    return allThreadsFinished;
}
```

One tip which can help a little in synchronizing the threads: You can save all the threads in a list and join them from main thread.

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < nrThreads; i++)
{
 var localStartNum = startNum; // save value in local variable
                                  // and use in the thread start
 var _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => 
                      MarkPrimes(localStartNum,
                                 Math.Min(localStartNum + interval, nrNums), i));
 startNum = startNum + interval;
 _thread.IsBackground = true;
 _thread.Start();
    threads.Add(_thread);
}

foreach(var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: @Para, you're right, another bug exists in the code. `AllThreadsFinished` always evaluates false. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: ah yes, that way it, thanks. Feel stupid now. But the local declarations that were missing were the big blunder. Thanks